# SqlException: Cannot open database

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp.net-core

I have problem with the IIS itself it seems that the database could not authenticate.  The error shows like this:

> SqlException: Cannot open database "dbPEMCOLoan" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\IAMPRO$'.

The problem right now is that I don't have any workgroup on my computer.  See picture below:

[image]

and also here is my connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"PEMCOLoan": "Data Source=IAMPRO;Initial Catalog=dbPEMCOLoan;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;"
```

}

I'm a bit new with the asp.net core framework and I'm trying my best to do the research on my own to fix the issue and tried those suggestions but never of them work because I couldn't find the domain `WORKGROUP\IAMPRO$` itself.

Any help would be very much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: `WORKGROUP\IAMPRO$` is the local machine user account your IIS Application Pool runs and thus is used for `Integrated Security`. Configure your Application Pool to run under a different user that is granted access.

Comment: Thank you so much! I set the Identity to my account and works like a charm! Right now I know why.  Thank you so much for this and I got the idea from you! Please make an answer so I could rate. Thanks @Filburt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WORKGROUP\IAMPRO$` is the local machine user account your IIS Application Pool runs and thus is used for *Integrated Security* (specified in your connection string).

Configure your Application Pool to run under a different user that is already granted access to your database or create a new, dedicated user account.

Using a dedicated user account is considered best practice since it allows to grant the specific privileges needed (on database and OS) and your App will not break when the password of your own user account is changed.